# Typescript type definitions - How to install all in current package.json?

Tags: json, node.js, typescript

I have an old NodeJS project that has a `package.json` file with all dependencies of the project, some of them with frozen versions which I would like to keep so that my code would not be broken due to deprecations.

Now I am migrating to TypeScript, and would like to automatically install all type definitions of all the libraries present in the existing `package.json` file.

I understand that there is a tool called `typings` that can install and manage the type definitions, but I'd like to avoid of a manual script to install all type definitions using it. There must be a more elegant way...

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

The tool you're probably referring to is `tsd` and its configuration is usually placed in `tsd.json` and the usual place for `d.ts` files is `typings` folder.

Then you can configure `package.json` as described on the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) project.

Also you can find very recent discussion about further developments in this topic [in this DefinitelyTyped issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/265)

**UPDATE:** `tsd` is deprecated in favour to its successor [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings) so naming in the question is correct.